# django form does not accessible from inherited templates

Tags: django, forms, inheritance, django-templates

I have a second-base.html that is parent of user-image.html 
when I load second-base.html I pass it some forms and all forms are reachable and every things are ok . but when I link to user-image.html that is socond-base.html 's child I cant access forms .

if any body could help me

here is my view.py

```
def dashboard(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
if request.method == 'GET':
    questioner_form = QuestionerForm()
    return render_to_response('second-level-base.html', locals(), context)
```

and here is my second-base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<title> {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{% block head %} {% endblock head%}
</head>
<body>
 <div class="modal fade " id="questionerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"      aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header" >
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>        
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" id="questionerForm"  role="form"   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'Questioner' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
        {{questioner_form.as_p}}           
       </div>
    </form>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

and here is part of my inhirented userimage.html which to needs access forms which passed to it's parent ( second-base.html)

```
 {% extends 'second-level-base.html' %}
 {% load static %}
 {% block title %} User Image {% endblock %}
 {% block body %}
 {{questioner_form.as_p}}
 {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I'v add code . if you could help me . tnx alot

Comment: How are you rendering userimage.html ? .. it should be rendered the same as my second-base.html

Comment: you mean that I should pass my form in function that render userimage.html ? is it not against DRY . once I pass forms to the parent template and I could user it in it's child !!!???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates I can see that you have to use `include` to make the forms of your `second-base.html`'s template available to `userimage.html`.